# Change numbers in a list in order to have a specific percentage of multiples in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I'm trying to create a complicated program in Python. There are 9 prime numbers that I want to use (2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23). I want to generate a list of 100 number so that exactly 99 of them are a multiple of 2, exactly 98 of them are a multiple of 3 and so on...

I have no strategy on how to implement this because all the numbers have to change accordingly to each other which makes things very complicated.

If the list is generated correctly, the following code should output:

```
result_list = [#This is the list that needs to be generated]
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]
for prime in primes:
    count = 0
    for item in result_list:
        if item % prime == 0:
            count += 1
    print(str(prime) + ": " + str(count))
```

Output:

```
2: 99
3: 98
5: 97
7: 96
11: 95
13: 94
17: 93
19: 92
23: 91
```

Anyone know how to do this?

EDIT:

I'm trying to get the fraction of the numbers that is divisible by all of the prime numbers multiplied together. The goal is to get this fraction as small as possible.

One problem is that although 91 of the numbers are multipliers of 23, not necessarily all of them are a multiple of 2.

Answer (score 3):

```
def primes_upto(limit):
    prime = [True] * limit
    for n in range(2, limit):
        if prime[n]:
            yield n # n is a prime
            for c in range(n*n, limit, n):
                prime[c] = False # mark composites

def generate_list(primes, total_length):
    result_list = [1] * total_length
    for i in range(total_length):
        result_list = result_list[0:i + 1] + [j * primes[i] for j in result_list[i+1:total_length]]
    return result_list

primes = list(primes_upto(542))
total_length = 100
result_list = generate_list(primes, total_length)
```

This ensures you have 100 distinct values with no repeats that will get you exactly what you need.

You can run this to check that the counts match up.

```
for prime in primes[:9]:
    count = sum(1 for item in result_list if item % prime == 0)
    print(f"{prime}: {count}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking this.  Just start out with an array of 1s.  Now skip the first and multiply the rest by 2.  Skip the first 2 and multiply the rest by 3.  Skip the first 3, and multiply the rest by 5.

```
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]
nums = [1]*100
for i, prime in enumerate(primes):
    for j in range(i+1,100):
        nums[j] *= prime
print(nums)
```

This only creates 10 distinct values -- the final 90 are repeated.  That satisfies your requirement, but if you want distinct values. you could just make the rest multiples.

```
for i in range(90):
    nums[10+i] = nums[9] * (i+1)
```

Comment: Note the word "exactly" in "exactly 99 of them are a multiple of 2" :-p In order to "just make the rest multiples", I suggest using prime factors starting at 29, rather than `(i+1)`.

Comment: Thank you, this did solve what I asked, although my question was written incorrectly, I will make an edit now. I do apologise.

Answer (score 1):

Just initialise your 100 numbers at `1`, then choose 99 numbers to multiply by 2, then 98 numbers to multiply by 3, etc.

To choose randomly, use `random.sample`.

```py
from random import sample

factors = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]
numbers = [1 for _ in range(100)]
for k, f in zip(range(99, 0, -1), factors):
    for i in sample(range(100), k):
        numbers[i] *= f

print(numbers)
# [74364290, 690690, 223092870, 111546435, 13123110, 74364290, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 31870410, 223092870, 17160990, 13123110, 223092870, 223092870, 13123110, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 9699690, 17160990, 9699690, 223092870, 746130, 223092870, 9699690, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 11741730, 13123110, 223092870, 17160990, 223092870, 223092870, 17160990, 223092870, 11741730, 223092870, 17160990, 223092870, 9699690, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 9699690, 223092870, 11741730, 13123110, 44618574, 223092870, 223092870, 20281170, 4056234, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 44618574, 13123110, 223092870, 31870410, 9699690, 9699690, 31870410, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 11741730, 11741730, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 20281170, 223092870, 223092870, 20281170, 223092870, 223092870, 20281170, 223092870, 1677390, 223092870, 223092870, 11741730, 223092870, 223092870, 223092870, 9699690, 223092870]
```

Comment: As you can see from my edit, this isn't sxactly what i'm looking for, I'm thinking that maybe if we considered that we don't start at 1 (since we want the smallest fraction possible) and implement what was said in the edit, it would give the answer. The problem is I don't know how to implement this

Comment: @BobTheBuilder Okay; so instead of random sampling we should choose a sample that minimises the number of equal numbers. So for instance, 91 numbers are multiples of 23 and 9 numbers are not. Of these 91 numbers, some are divisible by 19 and some are not; since 92 numbers are divisible by 19, the best split we can have is 81 / 10. And of these 81 numbers, some are multiples of 17 and some are not; since 93 numbers are multiples of 17, the best split we can have is 74 / 7. etc

Comment: I understand the concept, but why is the best split 84/6. How did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: @BobTheBuilder You have 91 numbers which are multiples of 23 and 9 numbers which are not. Then you need to choose 92 multiples of 19. The best you can do is put 9 multiples of 19 on the 9 numbers which were already separated, and then you still have 81 multiples of 19 to choose among the 91 multiples of 23, so this gives a 81-10 split.

Comment: Do you know how to implement this in Python?

Comment: @BobTheBuilder Since it's always a 91/9 split or a 92/8 split or something unbalanced like that, and never close to a 50/50 split, the best strategy is to always try to split your currently largest class of numbers. So after having choosen the multiples of 23 you have two classes of numbers, 91 in one class and 9 in the other, so you try to put as few multples of 19 in the class that has 91 numbers; but you have to put at least `92 - 9 = 81` multiples of 19 in that class anyway. Then for the next iteration your largest class will have 81 numbers, and you have to put `93-19=74`multiples of 17

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256138/discussion-between-bob-the-builder-and-stef).